# Adding button to panel dynamically and getting it's parent ID

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created a page where I give admin's a way to change photos info (e.g. Title, Description, etc) All the controls on the page are added dynamically because I have more than one gallery of photos.

1. panel --> parent.
2. button .
3. title text box.
4. description text box.

In every panel,  I have button that when clicked, sends the changed information to the server where the photo info is stored (Flickr). The click event for this button is added dynamically, and I want to know if is possible to get the parent of the Button I just clicked on.

Here is the code where I add all my controls:

```
 //global veriables (this is only part of the code)
 Panel panel;
 Button button;
 for (int i = 0; i < photo.Length; i++) {
     photo[i] = new FlickerImages(photoSet.MediumURLS[i], photoSet.ThumbnailURLS[i], photoSet.Titles[i], photoSet.Descreption[i]);

     panel = new Panel();
     panel.ID = "panel" + i;

     button = new Button();
     button.ID = "sendDataButton" + i;
     button.Text = "send data";
     button.Click += button_Click; //adding the event

     label = new Label();
     label.ID = "editLabel" + i;

     panel.Controls.Add(label);
     panel.Controls.Add(photo[i].CurrentImage(i)); //Image control
     panel.Controls.Add(photo[i].EditTitleTextBox(i)); //TextBox control
     panel.Controls.Add(photo[i].EditCommentTextBox(i)); //TextBox control
     panel.Controls.Add(button);

     Form.Controls.Add(panel);
}
```

Here is the click event I add to all the buttons:

```
void button_Click(object obj, EventArgs e) {
    Response.Write(button.Parent.ID); // i get panel10 every time this get fired.
}
```

I know this is possible with jQuery but is it possible to get the button ID in ASP.NET?

Sorry for my English and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, but are you looking for the `ClientID` property? (`button.Parent.ClientID`)

Edit:

You should reference the sending button in the event handler:

```
void button_Click(object obj, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write(((Button)obj).Parent.ID); 
}
```

Comment: i just tried that and i get the same result (panel10) any other idea?

Comment: What is the result you're looking for?

Comment: the result should change by the parent of the button id name.

Comment: See updated answer.. You are referencing the `button` _variable_ which is set to the last button you added to the panel. You should reference the button that invoked the click event. The invoker is passed to the `button_Click` function as the first argument which is `obj`.

Comment: exactly what i wanted,Thank you :)